# Cocoa Screensaver Embed Quartz

Tags: xcode, macos, cocoa, quartz-graphics, screensaver

I am trying to create a screensaver in Xcode to deploy as a .saver file.

However, I want to embed a Quartz Composition file (QTZ) into it.

As there is no XIB or NIB in a  screensaver template, how does one embed a qtz with code?

Here's what's in the ScreenSaverView.h:

```
#import <ScreenSaver/ScreenSaver.h>
@interface XmasView : ScreenSaverView
@end
```

And in ScreenSaverView.m,

```
#import "ScreenSaverView.h"

@implementation XmasView

- (id)initWithFrame:(NSRect)frame isPreview:(BOOL)isPreview
{
self = [super initWithFrame:frame isPreview:isPreview];
if (self) {
    [self setAnimationTimeInterval:1/30.0];
}
return self;
}

- (void)startAnimation
{
    [super startAnimation];
}

- (void)stopAnimation
{
    [super stopAnimation];
}

- (void)drawRect:(NSRect)rect
{
    [super drawRect:rect];
}

- (void)animateOneFrame
{
    return;
}

- (BOOL)hasConfigureSheet
{
    return NO;
}

- (NSWindow*)configureSheet
{
    return nil;
}

@end
```

I presume I have to put some code in initWithFrame: to embed the quartz composition? If so, what would I have to put in?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to create a `QCView` instance and place it as a subview of your screensaver view:

**.h**:

```
#import <ScreenSaver/ScreenSaver.h>
#import <Quartz/Quartz.h>

@interface XmasView : ScreenSaverView
@property (strong) QCView* qtzView;
@end
```

**.m**:

```
#import "ScreenSaverView.h"

@implementation XmasView
@synthesize qtzView;

- (id)initWithFrame:(NSRect)frame isPreview:(BOOL)isPreview
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame isPreview:isPreview];
    if (self) 
    {
        [self setAnimationTimeInterval:1/30.0];

        //create the quartz composition view
        qtzView = [[QCView alloc] initWithFrame: NSMakeRect(0, 0, NSWidth(frame), NSHeight(frame))];
        //make sure it resizes with the screensaver view
        [qtzView setAutoresizingMask:(NSViewWidthSizable|NSViewHeightSizable)];

        //match its frame rate to your screensaver
        [qtzView setMaxRenderingFrameRate:30.0f];

        //get the location of the quartz composition from the bundle
        NSString* compositionPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"YourComposition" ofType:@"qtz"];
        //load the composition
        [qtzView loadCompositionFromFile:compositionPath];

        //add the quartz composition view
        [self addSubview:qtzView];
    }
    return self;
}

//...implementation continues
```

Comment: This is not working with Xcode 6.4.  The subview is created, but the composition never renderers.

I considered using a QCRenderer to render the composition explicitly but gave up: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/QuartzFramework/Classes/QCRenderer_Class/